# How to change the colors inside html ul and reverse colors in hover effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I add this menu in bootstrap.
i wanted them to display in the following ways:

- case-1: If menu get drop down then display text color white, 
  background-color green.
- case-2: if any menu option is hovered then, **reverse their colors** in
  **hover** effect.

But the **`<a>`** tags are not getting the colors that i define in a class 'menu' for **`<ul>`** under which all **`<a>`** tags reside.I want to change their color in way so that other  **`<a>`** tags outside of menu won't change their style.

Please check image given below:

[image]

please suggest me on fixing this problem.

Here is the source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style media="screen" type="text/css"> 
         .menu{
         background-color:#4da309; 
         color: #FFFFFF; 
         font-size:20px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" >
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#" style="font-size:24px;">
                  File Menu<span class="caret"></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu menu">
                     Text gets Correct color
                     <li>Text gets Correct color <a href="" target="_blank">Information wrong color</a></li>
                     <li><a href="" target="_blank">Information wrong color</a></li>
                     <li><a href="" target="_blank">Information wrong color</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

please let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the "a tag" inside the Ul > Li.

As for the hovering state, just add a ":hover" to whatever you're trying to give a custom hover state CSS to.

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">  
     .menu{
         background-color:#4da309; 
         color: #FFFFFF; 
         font-size:20px;
     }

     .menu li a{
         color: #FFFFFF;
      }

     .menu li a:hover{
         color: #000000;
      }


  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your CSS so that `<a>` tags outside of menu won't change their style:

```
    .menu li a{
      background-color:#4da309; 
      color: #FFFFFF; 
      font-size:20px;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style media="screen" type="text/css"> 
         .menu{
         background-color:#4da309; 
         color: #FFFFFF; 
         font-size:20px;
         }
        .menu li a{
         background-color:#4da309; 
         color: #FFFFFF; 
         font-size:20px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" >
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#" style="font-size:24px;">
                  File Menu<span class="caret"></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu menu">
                     Text gets Correct color
                     <li>Text gets Correct color <a href="" target="_blank">Information wrong color</a></li>
                     <li><a href="" target="_blank">Information wrong color</a></li>
                     <li><a href="" target="_blank">Information wrong color</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `bootstrap` overrides your CSS because its selector is more selective:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #333;
}
```

If you want to override bootstrap, you need to take precedence over the `bootstrap` selector (after the inclusion of `bootstrap.css`):

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

Your should learn how CSS precedence works, [here](http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) is a good article (maybe you'll understand why CSS is called CSS!).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style media="screen" type="text/css"> 
         .menu{
         background-color:#4da309; 
         color: #FFFFFF; 
         font-size:20px;
         }
         .menu a{
         color: #FFFFFF !important;
         }
         .menu a:hover{
         color: #4da309 !important;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" >
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#" style="font-size:24px;">
                  File Menu<span class="caret"></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu menu">
                     Text gets Correct color
                     <li>Text gets Correct color <a href="" target="_blank">Information wrong color</a></li>
                     <li><a href="" target="_blank">Information wrong color</a></li>
                     <li><a href="" target="_blank">Information wrong color</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a hover event on ".dropdown-toggle". For example

```
if($("."dropdown-menu").is(':visible')){
  var anchor = $(this).find("a");

      anchor.addClass("greenText");   // Add your css style in this class

      anchor.hover(function(){
         $(_this).addClass("whiteText")  // Add hover css style
      }, function(){
         $(_this).addClass("greenText")  // Add hover css style
      })
   }
```